# Corruption when passing reference argument to dll

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, pass-by-reference, corruption

At first, I'm using OpenCV 2.4.2 with Visual 2008 on WinXp. Here is the problem:

I'm using the `imwrite` function to write gray leveled image which has the following prototype:

`bool imwrite( const string& filename, InputArray img, const vector<int>& params=vector<int>());`

The image type is previously checked and set (8bits, 1channel).
However, I've got an exception in the Release mode only (error -2, could not find a writer for the specified extension) to write a bmp image, in my case `.\Images\Debug\calibration_ref.bmp`.
I didn't understand what were wrong with this file name.

[image: Clue]

After looking deep into dll source file (opencv_highgui242d.dll, loadsave.cpp, l.298), I realised that the parameter `const std::string & filename` (at least this one...) was corrupted (or freed?) due to the `<Bad Ptr>`. To get this result, I used the highgui debug version dll in the Release mode, else, with the highgui release version, I get trash string instead. I suspect all the arguments to be corrupted.

[image: Clue2]

I've absolutely no idea where this corruption come from! I searched here and there but all I could find is related to optimisation disabling in release mode then bug fixing and [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813810/en-us) on string class about thread safe but i'm not sure that's the issue.

I'd add that the OpenCV version I use is not a package. I built it particularly with TBB (ver 4.0 6005). Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: You don't need to call `c_str()` because the function takes the parameter as a reference-to-const, so just `imageName` is good enough and will prevent the creation of a temporary object.

Comment: Is `imageName` a `std::string` ?

Comment: @cdmh
Yes, imageName is a `std::string`. I precisely added `c_str()` method to create a copy in order to check if the name wasn't destroyed during the function call and was at the origin of the bug. It wasn't here at the beginning and I removed it now.

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to pinpoint the problem. It could be mixing release/debug builds or mixing static/dynamic runtimes.

Comment: I don't know what static/dynamic runtimes means but yes probably :)
Ask me and I'll do my best.

Comment: In Project Properties, under Code Generation, the Runtime Library is specified. You have `Multi-threaded /MT` (static) or `Multi-threaded DLL /MD` (dynamic) and then for Debug `Multi-threaded Debug /MTd` (static) or `Multi-threaded DLL Debug /MDd` (dynamic)

Comment: Debug and release modes have respectively /MD and /MDd. Does that enlighten you?

Comment: There's your problem then. Debug and Release should have /MDd and /MD respectively

Comment: Ok, I fixed it but it does the same thing anyway :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the static initialization order.

Because the file name is declared as static which depends of other statics (I have a lot of static variable int this project), I have got uninitialized variable as parameter. This is the reason why it raised the exception with bad argument.

I could track this phenomenon thanks to breakpoints at the variable initialization and the execution of the function. The execution happened first...
However, it could be a good idea to make a trace of the parameter (rather an `OutputDebugString` or something to force display since trace won't work in release mode) before entering in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a release build, so the debugger will not be able to display all values because the optimisations will remove some objects. I think you went down a rabbit hole with the "corruption".

You say the error is `error -2, could not find a writer for the specified extension` so have you looked to find out why this is? What writer is used in Debug mode, and why isn't is available in Release mode. It may just be a missing DLL in your working directory.

I recommend changing your output filename too, so you don't get confused with output from each build. `.\Images\Debug\calibration_ref.bmp` might be better as `.\Images\Release\calibration_ref.bmp`, for example.